# Give part of LDAP tree access to SVN repository

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, repository, ldap

This is a relatively simple question. The company I work for has an SVN server with multiple repositories. Everyone has access to this one repository in particular; it contains employee contact numbers, and generic stuff like this.

We have LDAP based authentication for the SVN server. The problem is that the access is controlled by an Apache access file:

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile /www/company/svn/access
```

So I'm lazy, and I don't want to add new users manually to this generic repository. If they have an LDAP account, they should automatically get access without me having to manually edit the file and add their account name.

Say for example, I want all users in this DN to have access:

```
o=Somecompany,ou=Organizations,dc=somecompany,dc=net
```

Is there anyway to tell Apache to give users in an LDAP DN automatic access?